# Operator += giving undefined results

Tags: javascript

I am creating a post processor for our CAM software and hit a roadblock...the following Javascript is generating the results below.  I am very close, but how can I get rid of the "undefined" at the beginning?  I am at wit's end. 
Thank you

```
function onSection() {
    var Comp = hasParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        ? getParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        : " ";
    var dComp = "";

    if (Comp == "control") {         
        dComp = "D" + tool.diameterOffset + ", ";
    } else {
        return;
    }
    programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
}
```

results:

```
undefinedD46, D46, D25,
```

Comment: If `programInfo["program.comp"]` has never been initialized, its value is `undefined`.

Comment: Probable programInfo is never inizialited. Try var programInfo = [];

Comment: @Curlas if `programInfo` were undefined, `programInfo["program.comp"]` would throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: `programInfo["program.comp"] = programInfo["program.comp"] || ''; programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;`

Comment: @Amy yes, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`programInfo["program.comp"]` is apparently `undefined` before you reach the last line of your code.  That's the only possible source of the `undefined`.

Ensure it contains a valid string before concatenating to it.

```
if (!programInfo["program.comp"]) {
    programInfo["program.comp"] = "";
}

programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
```

Comment: Thank you!!! that worked.  i voted up but don't have 15 reputation yet.  i will get it marked as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an initial value before you can append.  In javascript, uninitialized values are undefined.

```
function onSection() {
    var Comp = hasParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        ? getParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        : " ";
    var dComp = "";

    if (Comp == "control") {         
        dComp = "D" + tool.diameterOffset + ", ";
    } else {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure the field exists, if not, set it to empty string
    var hasField = programInfo["program.comp"] !== undefined;
    if (!hasField) programInfo["program.comp"] = ""

    programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`programInfo["program.comp"]` is probably not initialized yet.
As you don't want to erase its value, that should probably be done conditionally:

```
function onSection() {
    var Comp = hasParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        ? getParameter("operation:compensationType") 
        : " ";
    var dComp = "";

    if (Comp == "control") {         
        dComp = "D" + tool.diameterOffset + ", ";
    } else {
        return;
    }
    if (!programInfo["program.comp"]) {
      programInfo["program.com"] = "";
    }
    programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you get an undefined because the property is undefined. So you need to initialize it.

Best solution, when you define programInfo, set `"program.comp"` to an empty string

Other solutions is to see if it is set, if not set it to an empty string

```
programInfo["program.comp"] = programInfo["program.comp"] || ''
programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
```

Or use an if/else to add it

```
if!(programInfo["program.comp"]) {
  programInfo["program.comp"] = dComp;
} else { 
  programInfo["program.comp"] += dComp;
}
```